# using custom resource/protocol in @PropertySource in Spring using custom ResourceLoader

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi I want to use @PropertySource in spring for a custom resource ie say xyz://path/x.txt instead of standard protocols like classpath file and so on which it already supports .I have found a way to do the same in spring Boot that is by SpringApplication as below with a custom ResourceLoader

```
 protected WebApplicationContext run(SpringApplication app){
  app.setResourceLoader(new MyCustomResourceLoader);
  return (WebApplicationContext )app.run();
 }
```

The same works well and now I can define propertySource like @PropertySource("xyz://path/y.txt") .But I was not able to figure out how to override/customize the same in a normal spring application .Though of trying ways by using ResourceLoaderAware and BeanPostProcessor but couldnt figure it out.

Any help ..

**UPDATE**
Stuff I will do in my custom ResourceLoader

```
public Class CustomResourceLoader extends DefaultResourceLoader{

@Override
public Resource getResource(String location){
if(location.startsWith("xyz://"){
return new XYZResource(new URI(location));
}
return super.getResource(location);
}
```

Now I just need a way to tell spring to use this instead of the defaultresourceloader it's possible as I mentioned in SPring boot but need to figure out how to do it in pure Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @chris-beams, who gave a workaround. Summarizing, the following changes required:

Extend AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext and override its getResource method by using your custom resourceloader as below

```
   @Override
   public Resource getResource(String location)
   {
      ResourceLoader loader = SingletongINSTANCE.getCustomResourceLoader();
      return loader.getResource(location);
   }
```

This can be done with either by using the custom AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext  entry in web.xml or via WebApplicationInitializer .

Also for more convenient support for custom resource loaders raised https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13905

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `ConfigurableEnvironment`, where you'll find first-class support for registering and ordering custom `PropertySource` instances:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html

Comment: Is one way to do it but can't it be simpler as in spring boot using a custom resource loader which extends the DefaultResourceLoader and has code to handle the new protocol example: aws s3: for properties in s3. Hence by this I can still use the @propertysource annotation to provide uri for custom protocols . not sure if this can be done using pure spring?

Comment: `GenericApplicationContext` exposes a `#setResourceLoader` that will be used preferentially if set. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#setResourceLoader-org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader-

Comment: So for example, try spinning up an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` in a main method. Configure it with your custom `ResourceLoader` and register a `@Configuration` class annotated with a `@PropertySource` annotation that uses your custom resource loading prefix. Everything should hook up.

Comment: Thanks @chris-beams good pointers these .. was wondering can this be done in a webapp via AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ,though that doesn't expose setResourceLoader there .Hope things were smoother as in the case of boot :)

Comment: Might be worth filing a JIRA issue about getting equivalent `#setResourceLoader` support on the `ACWAC` side. In the meantime, a reasonable workaround may be to simply override `ACWAC#getResource` method, and delegate there to your custom `ResourceLoader` implementation. Doing this within a `WebApplicationInitializer` will probably be most convenient. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

Comment: Thanks :) ..yup that way worked @chris-beams will put in a post with the answer that worked for me also will raise a JIRA issue to add more cleaner support ..